# Allow wordpress users with specified role to comunicate with nodejs backend

Tags: php, node.js, wordpress, express

I have created a website using wordpress for handle the frontend and also a nodejs server with expressjs for do some tasks in the backend.

I'm facing this problem now, I want that only the authenticated admin users in the wordpress server are able to acces some specific endpoints of the node backend api.

So let's say that i create a wordpress page that has a form that makes a POST request to nodejs to an admin endpoint ( /api/admin ).

- I should make that the page is only accesible from the admins, and this is easly done by wordpress settings
- I must add some functions on the nodejs server that checks if the request come directly from the wordpress admin to avoid for example that someone just send a POST request through postman

Actually i tried to see the wp Api but i didn't find nothing useful, I'm stuck on how i should handle this problem and how i should move, any advices?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to authenticate requests coming to your node.js backend. What you need here is to implement custom authentication plugins may be jwt plugin.

more info here https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/#authentication-plugins

So basically you can pass access tokens to your node.js backend after authentication and then in your node.js backend you can validate that token and authorize.